# Apache server wont start - MAMP

Tags: apache, mamp

I'm very new to MAMP, when I first installed MAMP the Apache server and mySQL were working fine.

Then I stupidly deleted my root user on the database, and I couldn't access the mySQLadmin screen.

So I uninstalled MAMP and reinstalled, but now the Apache server isn't working.

Anyone got suggestions, for example what logs I should look at? I've researched a few solutions but im pretty confused

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem. 
Make sure you remove all files from /applications/mamp before reinstalling MAMP! If this doesn't work, it's possible you messed something else up, so you can try installing XAMPP, which offers just about the same functionality as MAMP.